# Can't import socket.io-client (v2.4.0) in my typescript project

Tags: typescript, socket.io, react-typescript, socket.io-client

It says [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client/v/2.4.0) that I can import it like this:
`import io from 'socket.io-client';`

But doing this I'm getting an error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'socket.io-client'. '/.../project/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/socket.io-client` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'socket.io-client';`ts(7016)
```

I have tried installing `@types/socket.io-client` but the error doesn't go away.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, it worked importing this way:

```
const io = require("socket.io-client/dist/socket.io")
```